# xml parsing with simple xml

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with simpleXML and entity not being defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426852/problem-with-simplexml-and-entity-not-being-defined)

I have this tag with an entity in an xml file:

```
<comune>Forli&#39;</comune>
```

Simple xml in php fail to parse the file:

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: parser error : Entity 'igrave' not defined

How can i do?

Comment: That's not the line that's throwing the error.  The line would have something like `&igrave;` in it.  What you posted above is 100% valid XML...

Comment: Tell the author of the XML document to use the Unicode value or provide a DTD where the entity is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this a small example and it worked for me

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<comune>
<comune>Forli&#39;</comune>
</comune>
```

PHP:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

    foreach($xml->children() as $child){ 
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r((string)$child);
        echo '</pre>asd';
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Forli'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426852/problem-with-simplexml-and-entity-not-being-defined) for help